# When will Enterprise users be required to update to the modern version of Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, microsoft-edge

When will Microsoft Edge Legacy be officially gone, worldwide?

As I understand, the first Chrome-based version of Edge was released in `January 2020`, **but** it didn't start rolling out worldwide via Windows Update to users until `June 2020`.

Windows 10 requires all Home users to update within 30 days, and all Enterprise users to update within 365 days.

So will Enterprise users be forced to update one year after the original release (in January 2021)? Or one year after it was pushed to users via Windows Update (in June 2021)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because either the user hasn't done enough self research themselves or this isn't publically known/discussed information - either way this very specifically isn't the kind of question served by this site.

Comment: @Chopper3 I've been searching the internet for the last two hours for this information. And if ServerFault isn't the correct StackExchange, perhaps you can point me toward a better one? This is, after all, a question that a sysadmin can answer.

Comment: Probably relevant while likely not the full answer: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4533505/what-is-microsoft-edge-legacy

Comment: March 9, 2021: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge

Comment: @GregAskew Thank you. (I am astonished that you have an answer so fast.) Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted? ....It doesn't DIRECTLY answer the question (How long is the longest that Enterprise users can delay the update), but it's close enough to what I needed. Presumably if they're dropping support in March 2021, then the answer is "January 2021".

Comment: Making everything on the game graphics engine is a huge security mistake. Unfortunately all big ones have been assimilated. You can't force-to anything. You can still use IE8 if needed.

Comment: @Overmind Our primary concern, and the reason for the question, is backwards compatibility, not security. But thank you, nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

March 9, 2021:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge

What is the Lifecycle policy for Microsoft Edge?

Microsoft Edge follows the Modern Policy. Feature updates are released on an approximate six-week cycle. Go here for servicing guidelines.

End of support for the legacy version of the Microsoft Edge desktop app is on March 9, 2021. This means that Microsoft Edge Legacy will not receive security updates after that date.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-365-apps-say-farewell-to-internet-explorer-11-and/ba-p/1591666